# A Common ODBC Connection Strings works for SQL Server 2005+

Tags: sql-server, connection, odbc

I am using CDatabase in VC2008 to connect to SQL Server via ODBC.

I want to use a common connection string that can work for SQL Sever 2005 and all higher versions.

I check https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/ and see there are many different kinds of connection strings.

Whether I should use:

Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;

or

Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
Pwd=myPassword;

**Update:**

Based on my test, using Driver={SQL Server} or Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0} can both connect to SQL Server 2008. I guess the former will works for all SQL Server versions, but the latter will only works for SQL Server 2008. Please confirm my guess.

Comment: I would expect either to work with all SQL versions. However, `Driver={SQL Server}` is using the deprecated ODBC driver included with Windows whereas newer ODBC drivers are separate installs nowadays. I suggest you use the latest [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) and specify `Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}.

Answer (score 4):

Both driver will connect to Sql Server.But purpose of both drivers are different.

> `Driver={SQL Server} :`

It is called Windows Data Access Components (WDAC).

It do not support new feature of `Sql server 2005+ like xml data type,Multiple active result sets (MARS), user-defined data types (UDT), query notifications` etc.

It support only Read Committed transaction isolation.

> `Driver={SQL Native Client}`

This driver is suitable for  application that need to take advantage of new feature of Sql server 2005+.

It support both Read Committed transaction and snapshot transaction isolation level.

> `System.Data.SQLClient`

SQLClient is optimize for .NET and database Sql server 2000+.
It give maximum performance.

So if your application is new or existing then use `SQL Native Client`.It can access all feature of connected version of Sql server 2005,2008 etc.

`ODBC`  :Use ODBC when application is connected to multiple database or it is expected that database may change.DAL code is written in such a manner it will work for any database.

[Suggested Reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/updating-an-application-to-sql-server-native-client-from-mdac?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Common Connection** : I don't think there can be any common connection.Suppose in my system `SQL server native client 10` is install then I know that I cannot connect to `Sql server 2016 +` .`SQL server native client 10` will work for `Sql Server 2016` and below.

Of course by programming we can make dynamic connection string which will accept driver as parameter etc.

To connect to higher version ,s I will hv to upgrade my driver and do minor change in connection string.Or if you don't want to touch code then Use `DSN`.

Yes I forgot, `Driver={SQL Server Native Client}` it can connect to `Sql Srver 2005` only.if you try to connect to higher version then it will throw error.

Comment: Sorry but based my test, using Driver={SQL Server} will work, but using Driver={SQL Native Client} will fail(Only use Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0} will work. I also use odbcad32 to check the drivers, there are only two drivers, i.e. "SQL Server" and "SQL Server Native Client 10.0". I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to write a program that will work with all versions of SQL Server 2005 and higher versions, then which driver string should I use?

Comment: @alancc , First say what is your Front end application like .net or c++.Then in 2-3 line mention what type of work your application will do.

Comment: My front application is Visual C++ 2008. My application needs to connect to SQL Server via ODBC and create a database and then create a table and add some records.

Comment: @alancc ,As per your requirement you should use  SQL Native Client.

Comment: What I need is a common connection SQL String that works for SQL Server 2005 and higher versions. But your answer does not provide such a solution at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205070/discussion-between-kumarharsh-and-alancc).

Comment: @alancc ,chat room do not open from my place.Your main question was never about Common Connection, nor you mention anywhere.Anyway now I seem to understand your question.Please read my edited Common connection onward.

Comment: "Common Connection" appear in both the title and the body, at the very beginning part. Thank you very much.